# Webscrapping returns []

Tags: python, web-scraping

it's a simple webscrapping and i'm having a lot of problems

it has to give me all the titles of a yt playlist

the html code:

```
<a id="video-title" class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-playlist-video-renderer" href="/watch?v=hnqRXZZAqPw&amp;list=PLojsoh8U3jSyIaRcvOhd6ecqsibcM0y2a&amp;index=1&amp;t=1542s" title="Annie Get Your Gun • Bernadette Peters • 1/3">
          Annie Get Your Gun • Bernadette Peters • 1/3
        </a>
```

my code:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
url = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLojsoh8U3jSyIaRcvOhd6ecqsibcM0y2a"
yt = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(yt.text, 'html.parser')

#t = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-playlist-video-renderer"})
```

> ##my first ideia was something like that, didnt work. then a friend said to me to do like this:

```
t = soup.select(".yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.ytd-playlist-video-renderer")

texts = [element.text.strip() for element in t]  

titles = [element.attrs.get("title") for element in t]  

print(t)
print(texts)
print(titles)
```

but it only returns:

[]

[]

[]

Comment: you may have the most common problem: page may use `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure of how requests works, but from my experience the HTML you get from `requests.get()` can be different from what you normally see from browser. This is related to how the server side (in this case, YouTube) works.
[Welcome for any in-depth explanation on this part].

A workaround is to use Selenium, a web scraping package that mimics a browser navigation. A minimal example:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLojsoh8U3jSyIaRcvOhd6ecqsibcM0y2a"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10) # sleep for awhile to make sure the page is loaded

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
t = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-playlist-video-renderer'})
texts = [element.text.strip() for element in t]  

print(texts)
```

When you run the code, a browser will fire up just as someone browsing.

Output:

```
[
    'Annie Get Your Gun • Bernadette Peters • 1/3',
    'Annie Get Your Gun • Bernadette Peters • 2/3', 
    ...
]
```